# Get ctor argument used in field's initializer using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

My assembly has multiple classes which have fields like this:

```
private static Foo MyFoo = new Foo(typeof(Bar));
```

The argument `typeof(Bar)` differs for each class.

In my unit tests, I need to extract that argument dynamically.

I can find all classes, and filter for those with a static `Foo` field. I then have a `FieldInfo`.

But then I don't know how to get *the type of that argument?*

Comment: Reflection is costly. Can't you use generics? Maybe you can tell what you want to do ?

Comment: Can you access the type of Bar from inside Foo? Or do you really need to analyse the argument itself i.e. the code?

Comment: @SteveB I don't think reflection for unit tests is a bad thing. It usually reduces the complexity of the `normal use` case.

Comment: All our testing code uses reflection. Its the one place where reflection is extremely useful, and the perf hit is irrelevant.

Comment: @Nebula No unfortunately. That would have made things easier. We need to get the type of that argument.

Comment: @hbob Then check my answer ;-) You'd need to go in that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for `MethodBodyReader`You can use that to look at the IL and fetch the type of the constructor argument there.

https://github.com/jbevain/mono.reflection/blob/master/Mono.Reflection/MethodBodyReader.cs

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FieldInfo.GetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the value of a `static`.

```
foreach (var foo in foos) {
  var myfoo = foo.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static).Single(fieldinfo =>  fieldinfo.FieldType == typeof(Foo));
  Foo foo = (Foo) myfoo.GetValue(null);
}
```

Now assuming `Foo` looks something like:

```
public Type AType {get; set; }
public void Foo(Type t) { AType = t; }
```

Then

```
Foo foo = (Foo) myfoo.GetValue(null);
Type fooType = foo.AType;
```

Comment: Yes I do that, but can't find a way to access the argument after that?

Comment: That would give him a `Foo` but what OP is asking for is `typeof(Bar)`

Comment: Please look at the rest of the answer.

Comment: Yes that would have been cool, but `Foo` doesn't expose it. :( So I was hoping there was a way to do it via reflection, but according to the other answers, there isn't.

Comment: That would be to open a can of works, since I can't change `Foo`. Apparently you can't analyse this using reflection, without dropping down to IL. It uses that argument to instantiate wrapped objects, which use it to do other stuff, which goes on and on. So I thought reflection would allow me to do it easily at the callsite, but apparently not.

Comment: All you need to look at is the constructor of `Foo` that takes a `Type` as its only parameter.  Once we know where the constructor stores the type when can then use reflection to get its value.

Comment: Your logic makes good sense. But in this case it doesn't get stored there. It gets passed into more objects, which in turn create more objects. So like I implied above, it would be too complicated. I was looking for an easy solution by analysing the callsite. I'll need to rethink this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection gives you a Metadata which is associated with the assembly. Not the runtime value which you're asking for.

What you're asking isn't possible with Reflection API unless you inspect the IL. You may use [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/) or similar libraries to inspect the IL.

Btw, if you explain what you're trying to test, It would be easy to answer. I believe you can easily test `MyFoo.SomeProperty == typeof(Bar)` given that `Foo` exposes the constructor argument as some property.

Comment: I'm trying to get the type of that argument. No it doesn't expose it, that's the problem.